# zsh, up arrow only repeats unique commands?

Tags: terminal, history, zsh

I'm looking for a setting that will make it so that when i hit the up arrow, zsh shows commands i have recently edited. The catch is, i only want *unique* commands. Currently, if i type `echo "hello world"` 50 times, i have to press up arrow 50 times to get the command i used *before* typing the echo command. This is annoying to say the least.

Any thoughts on what setting i need to enable/disable?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`HIST_IGNORE_ALL_DUPS` will throw out *all* previous matches of the command, which can be confusing when using the history as a log of what you did later:

> HIST_IGNORE_ALL_DUPS:
> If a new command line being added to the history list duplicates an older one, the older command is removed from the list (even if it is not the previous event).

A closer fit to your needs is probably the `HIST_FIND_NO_DUPS` option:

> HIST_FIND_NO_DUPS:
> When searching for history entries in the line editor, do not display duplicates of a line previously found, even if the duplicates are not contiguous.

Or maybe the `HIST_IGNORE_DUPS`, but, as [RichieHH](https://superuser.com/questions/273047/zsh-up-arrow-only-repeats-unique-commands/273382?noredirect=1#comment2444163_273382) notes, it also leads to an incomplete account of history:

> HIST_IGNORE_DUPS:
> Do not enter command lines into the history list if they are duplicates of the previous event.

See: `man zshoptions | less -p History`.

Comment: HIST_FIND_NO_DUPS is a better answer than mine I think.

Comment: Bash: `export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups`. ZSH: `setopt HIST_IGNORE_DUPS`

Comment: No, HIST_IGNORE_DUPS is not the best as it leaves the old instance as opposed to "refreshing it" in history.  HIST_FIND_NO_DUPS is good. HIST_IGNORE_ALL_DUPS *better* because it removes the oldest instance and inserts the newest. Way better to use history to remember where you were!

Answer (score 4):

I can't see any way to literally only do that, but if you set the `HIST_IGNORE_ALL_DUPS` option, only the most recent version of a command will be retained in history, giving you the same effect.

See `man zshoptions` for details.

Comment: Works great! Unless i am missing something, this is exactly what i wanted :)