# Get up-arrow key to only show unique commands? GHC Haskell

Tags: windows, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, command-history, ghc

*Haskell uses the GHC (Glasgow Haskell Compiler) which is basically a command line interface to compile and run Haskell.*

Like many popular CLI's, GHC allows you to use the up and down arrow keys to access previously used commands. However, it shows commands that you typed previously even if they are identical to the current commands. So if you typed ":r" 50 times for some reason, you would have to press the up arrow key 50 times to access the command you typed *before* that.

**Question:Is there anyway to configure ghc so the up arrow key only shows a history of *unique* commands you typed (on Windows)?**

My question is essentially this but for ghc: [zsh, up arrow only repeats unique commands?](https://superuser.com/questions/273047/zsh-up-arrow-only-repeats-unique-commands)

Answer (score 0):

Create `~/.haskeline` with the following contents:

```
historyDuplicates: ignoreConsecutive
```

You can also use `ignoreAll` for more aggressive pruning. [Docs](https://mpickering.github.io/ghc-docs/build-html/users_guide/ghci.html#the-haskeline-file)

Comment: Awesome! Where do I write this command: ```~/.haskeline w```?

Comment: It is not a command, it is a file you are supposed to create.

Comment: Ah ok. Where in windows do I make this file?

Comment: Sorry, no idea about Windows. :(